# Group policy not working

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi we have two offices at different locations, they are set up on active directory sites and services and the active directory is replicated between the two over a vpn.

I can see all the group policys at the other site and they all look the same but when we log in at the first site they get a default desktop and not the desktop that we have at the first site with programs that are launched at logon.

I guess this must be down to the programs and scripts we have that run on logon but this only happers for some users.

I am not sure what the scripts do currently but i thought i would post this here while im investigating it further incase any of you have encountered anything similar.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on http://serverfault.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the domain controller the PCs with the problems are connecting too by running SET at the command prompt of the PC and looking for the logon server
2. Once you know the logon server or the PC (when it's getting the issue) then open the GPMC and manually connect to this DC (right-click on the Domain and select "Change Domain Controller".
3. Now check that the GPOs show the settings as expected. If not then it's a replication problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help it turned out to be a replication problem and sorry for this being posted in wrong forum.